# Celery acknowledgement rate drops significantly when scaling worker pods

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Kubernetes deployment with Celery workers processing tasks. Each task involves:

```
Fetching a JSON payload from an MQTT server.
Performing computation on the payload.
Sending the computed payload via a POST request to an API endpoint.
The API endpoint writes the payload into a MongoDB database.
```

I've configured Celery with the following parameters:

bash

--loglevel=info 
--autoscale=2,20 
--without-gossip 
--without-mingle 
--prefetch-multiplier=2 
-n worker1.%h

The deployment includes two containers: one for the Celery instance and another for RabbitMQ.

The issue is that when I had only one pod (replica), the acknowledgement rate per second was around 250/s, which is expected for my small and non-CPU-intensive computations. However, when I increased the replicas to 3, the acknowledgement rate per second dropped to 90/s.

I'm using Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), and each pod runs on a single node with 8 cores (16 CPUs) and 16GB RAM.

I'd like to understand whether the performance degradation is due to MongoDB not handling three instances simultaneously or if there might be another bottleneck causing this issue.

Environment:

```
Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)
Celery
RabbitMQ
MongoDB
Kubernetes deployment with 3 replicas
Each node: 8 cores, 16GB RAM
Each Pod: celery instance and RabbitMQ instance .
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the Celery workers' performance with multiple replicas would be appreciated. Thank you!